# Getting link tag via DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I convert an atom feed into RSS using [atom2rss.xsl](https://github.com/kornelski/atom2rss/blob/master/atom2rss.xsl). Works fine.

Then, using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), I try to get the post title and URL:

```
$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $html);

if (!empty($feed) && is_object($feed) ) {
    foreach ($feed->getElementsByTagName("item") as $item){
        echo 'url: '. $item->getElementsByTagName("link")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo 'title'. $item->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }
    return;
}
```

But the post URL is empty.

See this [eval which contains HTML](https://eval.in/1055995). What am I doing wrong? I suspect I am not getting the link tag properly via `$item->getElementsByTagName("link")->item(0)->nodeValue`.

Comment: Why do you have to add the XML declaration, or if you have XML why not use http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that there are several `<link>` elements in each item and the one (I think) your interested in is the one with `rel="self"` as an attribute.  The quickest way (without messing around with XPath) is to loop over each `<link>` element checking for the right `rel` value and then take the `href` attribute from that...

```
if (!empty($feed) && is_object($feed) ) {
    foreach ($feed->getElementsByTagName("item") as $item){
        $url = "";
        // Look for the 'right' link tag and extract URL from that
        foreach ( $item->getElementsByTagName("link") as $link )    {
            if ( $link->getAttribute("rel") == "self" ) {
                $url = $link->getAttribute("href");
                break;
            }
        }
        echo 'url: '. $url;
        echo 'title'. $item->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }
    return;
}
```

which gives...

```
url: https://www.blogger.com/feeds/2984353310628523257/posts/default/1947782625877709813titleExtraordinary Genius - Cp274
```

Comment: Do you understand the concept of *you just saved my goddamn life*? Thank you so much.

Comment: No wait, the URL in the `$html` example above should be `https://translationnoob.blogspot.com/2018/09/extraordinary-genius-cp274.html`

Comment: That URL only seems to appear in the `rel="replies"` element as `https://translationnoob.blogspot.com/2018/09/extraordinary-genius-cp274.html#comment-form`

Comment: Indeed. This is [the actual atom feed](https://translationnoob.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default) I am testing with. EDIT: What I think is happening is that the [atom2rss.xsl](https://github.com/kornelski/atom2rss/blob/master/atom2rss.xsl) is messing up the conversion a bit.

Comment: That `<link>` element is missing - you could change the code to extract the one in there (`$link->getAttribute("rel") == "replies"`) and extract before the `#`.  Alternatively is to try and fix the translation to your current content and use `$link->getAttribute("rel") == "alternate"`.

Comment: If you test `$link->getAttribute("rel") == "replies"`, you will see that it grabs the incorrect URL. Any way to target the `replies` rel value containing the correct URL?

Comment: TBH - it's a bit of a hack.  It may be that if there are no replies then it won't work.

Comment: Although if you just remove the `break;` in the loop this may help.

Comment: I ended up going with [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/). I will still mark this answer as correct because it does correctly resolve the initial issue. Thanks! Lesson to learn, if you are dealing with feeds, use a library.

Answer (score 0):

```
   function get_links($link)
    {
        $ret = array();
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($link));
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
        foreach ($links as $tag){
            $ret[$tag->getAttribute('href')] = $tag->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        }

        return $ret;
    }
  print_r(get_links('http://www.google.com'));
```

OR u can use DOMXpath

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);

    // take all links
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

    for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
           $href = $hrefs->item($i);
           $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
           echo $url.'
    ';
```